# props.items.map is not a function using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React as a beginner, and I looked up the error I was getting and most people say you cannot use map with an object, it must be an array. But I am getting back the following data for my props.items when put in console.log:

```
[{
  ItemKey: 82521,
  ISBN: "158344422X",
  Title: "Butterflies And Moths",
  Publisher: "Benchmark Education",
  Illustrator: " "
}, {
  ItemKey: 85938,
  ISBN: "9780452274426",
  Title: "In the Time of the Butterflies",
  Publisher: "Penguin Plume",
  Illustrator: " "
}]
```

So it is returning an array. But I still get the map is not a function error. Here is my code:

```
function ItemGrid (props){
    return (
        <ul className='items-list'>
            {props.items.map(function(item, index){
                <li key={item.Title} className="items-list-item">
                </li>
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Does anyone see anything unusual about the code I wrote or the object getting returned?

EDIT: Here is how I am getting the data:

```
module.exports = {
    fetchItems: function(){
        var encodedURI = window.encodeURI('http://localhost:8081/items?Title=butterflies', { crossdomain: true });
        return axios.get(encodedURI).then(function(response){
            return response.data;
        });
    }
}
```

And I am passing data to ItemGrid through:

```
componentDidMount(){
    api.fetchItems().then(function(items){
        this.setState(function(){
            return {
                items: items
            }
        })
    }.bind(this));
}

render() {
    return (<div>
        <ItemGrid items={this.state.items} />
    </div>);
}
```

I am also having trouble getting the li items to show up once the data is present:

```
<ul className='items-list'>

            {items && items.map(function (item, index) {
                console.log(item);
                <li key={index} className='items-list-item'>
                    item.Title
                </li>
            })}
        </ul>
```

Comment: Where are you logging it?

Comment: did you get your items from API ?

Comment: You sure it's JSON and not still text?

Comment: show where and how you call `ItemGrid` i think that on the first render you got no items yet

Comment: how are you passing the props into the `ItemGrid` component?

Comment: Are you using redux?

Comment: I am not using redux. I am logging it from right before the return statement in ItemGrid. I am not sure it is JSON so I will try to parse it too. I think Sag1v is right, having no data is definitely an issue. Thanks all for the comments and help.

Comment: So I had an initial string set for my state. So that messed me up. I am getting my data now. Thanks all. But I am not getting any li items in my browser even though the console log gives me all of my titles.

Comment: never mind, wasn't returning data from within my map. Done now.

Comment: got any good redux tutorials for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render function can and will be called several times, often without any data the first time through.

So you need to check if your data is present before you try and iterate over it with the `map()` function.

if `props.items` is not present you can return something simple like null or even "Loading", and the next time around (when the data is there) it will work as expected.

So your new code could be this (only rendering if props.items is defined):

```
function ItemGrid (props){
    return (
        <ul className='items-list'>
            {props.items && props.items.map(function(item, index){
                <li key={item.Title} className="items-list-item">
                </li>
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Comment: nice short solution.

Comment: also needed to return the li group in my map function. But your warning was needed.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution depends on how the data is being retrieved. If it's a simple JS array within your script, the data should be available when the component is mounted.

```js
var data = [{
    ItemKey: 82521,
    ISBN: "158344422X",
    Title: "Butterflies And Moths",
    Publisher: "Benchmark Education",
    Illustrator: " "
  }, {
    ItemKey: 85938,
    ISBN: "9780452274426",
    Title: "In the Time of the Butterflies",
    Publisher: "Penguin Plume",
    Illustrator: " "
  }];

function ItemGrid(props) {
  var items = props.items;

  return ( 
    <ul className='items-list'> {
      items.map(function(item, index) { 
        return (<li key={item.ItemKey} className="items-list-item">{item.Title}</li>)
      })
    } </ul>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<ItemGrid items={data} />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

On the other hand, if you're retrieving the data from an asynchronous request it may not be available when the component is mounted and you'll need to handle the case when `props.items` is undefined/empty/null. In the example below we wrap the `<ItemsGrid/>` component in a `<Parent/>` component which passes the `items` as a prop to `<ItemsGrid/>`. Initially the `items` is `null`, and after 3 seconds it changes to an array. This simulates an asynchronous data source.

While `items` is `null` we return a list showing `Loading...`, and when `items` changes to a valid value we display the items.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
    
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      this.setState({
        data: [{
          ItemKey: 82521,
          ISBN: "158344422X",
          Title: "Butterflies And Moths",
          Publisher: "Benchmark Education",
          Illustrator: " "
        }, {
          ItemKey: 85938,
          ISBN: "9780452274426",
          Title: "In the Time of the Butterflies",
          Publisher: "Penguin Plume",
          Illustrator: " "
        }]
      })
    }.bind(this), 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <ItemGrid items={this.state.data} />
    )
  }
}

function ItemGrid(props) {
  var items = props.items;
  
  if (!items) {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>Loading...</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }

  return ( 
    <ul className='items-list'> {
      items && items.map(function(item, index) { 
        return (<li key={item.ItemKey} className="items-list-item">{item.Title}</li>)
      })
    } </ul>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I am using data coming in async. The conditions for my data are definitely on the right path. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using redux, this is a very easy fix, but if you aren't:

What is happening is when the component mounts, it immediately searches for `props.items`, but it is `null`. You have an asynchronous event that *eventually* gets the data, but it's not doing it fast enough.

The easiest way to fix this is to control what your `.map` is accepting by using a conditional statement before your component attempts to render content.

```
function ItemGrid (props){
    const items = props.items ? props.items : []
    return (
        <ul className='items-list'>
            {items.map(function(item, index){
                <li key={item.Title} className="items-list-item">
                </li>
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Check to see if `props.items` is `null` or not. If it is, render an empty array so it doesn't throw an error. If it does exist, it'll use `props.items`.

Please keep in mind that this will only work if a rerender attempt is made after you receive the array of data. I would personally uses promises and state to control rendering, because that will work in any situation. It's a much more involved solution, but it's something you should know like the back of your hand as a React developer. Keep us updated.

Comment: Good short solution, I added some extra details, I am still getting errors on json.parse. I think my data is not in the right format. I put the data into jsonlint but it did not have errors.

Comment: Got any tutorials that would explain how Redux would solve this without the condition?

Comment: Read up on what Redux is, if you're curious. It's a completely different way of handling data stored in your frontend. You should `console.log` what `props.items` looks like. If it's an object. something like `Object.entries` should help you use `map`.

Comment: yeah, i got it with map now. I was having an issue with the first value of my state, and returning the value within map. I wasn't doing that and nothing was showing up. doh! Im good now, thanks for your help.